# Nedb async function to be awaited

Tags: javascript, nedb

```
async function count() {
        let nedb = <<functional nedb database>>
        let count = 0
        await iterate(nedb, {}, g=>{
            count++
        })
        console.log(count)


iterate(xx, query, callback) {
    return new Promise((res, rej)=> {
        pkgs.find(query).exec((err, res)=>{
            if(err!==null) {
                this.err(err)
            } else {
                res.forEach((pkg)=>{
                    callback(pkg)
                })
            }
        })
        res()
    })
```

I would like to write something, after the iteration is over, is there way to do it in some normal way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `res()`olve call inside the `find` callback. Immediately fulfilling the promise to `undefined` won't help.

But you really shouldn't pass an iteration callback at all. Instead, write

```
async function count() {
    let nedb = …;
    let count = 0;
    const pkgs = await query(nedb, {});
    pkgs.forEach(pkg => count++);
    // or maybe better just:
    const count = pkgs.length;
    console.log(count);
}

function query(pkgs, query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        pkgs.find(query).exec((error, result)=>{
            if (error !== null) reject(error);
            else resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't want to count to one.

Comment: @m23 what do you mean? This still increments for each package.